# Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files in kubernetes

Tags: mysql

Today when I start mysql 5.7 in kubernetes cluster(v1.15.2),the log shows like this:

```
2020-05-15T10:37:34.751239Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-05-15T10:37:34.780623Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.27) starting as process 1 ...
2020-05-15T10:37:34.858717Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-05-15T10:37:34.858749Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-05-15T10:37:34.858755Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-15T10:37:34.858760Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-05-15T10:37:34.858764Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-15T10:37:34.858768Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-05-15T10:37:34.859166Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-15T10:37:34.859334Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-05-15T10:37:34.868209Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-05-15T10:37:34.895957Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-15T10:37:34.903259Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-05-15T10:37:34.922935Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2020-05-15T10:37:34.922969Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2020-05-15T10:37:34.922974Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
2020-05-15T10:37:35.923439Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2020-05-15T10:37:35.923469Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2020-05-15T10:37:36.923662Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2020-05-15T10:37:36.923701Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2020-05-15T10:37:37.923829Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2020-05-15T10:37:37.923856Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2020-05-15T10:37:38.924648Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2020-05-15T10:37:38.924689Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2020-05-15T10:37:39.929722Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2020-05-15T10:37:39.929750Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2020-05-15T10:37:40.929871Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2020-05-15T10:37:40.929900Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2020-05-15T10:37:41.930030Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
```

the mysql data file was mounted using NFSv4 in aliyun cloud, now I am check what service to using the `./ibdata1` using this command,but it shows no process using this file:

```
[root@log001 apollo-mysql]# ll
total 188460
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input     4096 Mar 22 18:10 ApolloConfigDBDEV
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input     4096 Apr 28 09:58 ApolloConfigDBTEST
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input     4096 Apr 29 15:40 ApolloConfigDBUAT
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input     4096 Apr 28 10:20 ApolloPortalDB
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input       56 Mar 22 12:26 auto.cnf
-rw------- 1 polkitd input     1679 Mar 22 12:26 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 polkitd input     1107 Mar 22 12:26 ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 polkitd input     1107 Mar 22 12:26 client-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 polkitd input     1675 Mar 22 12:26 client-key.pem
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input     1048 May  2 09:56 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input 50331648 May 15 13:05 ib_logfile0
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input 50331648 May 15 13:05 ib_logfile1
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input 79691776 May 15 13:05 ibdata1
-rw-r----- 1 polkitd input 12582912 May 15 13:10 ibtmp1
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input     4096 Mar 22 12:26 mysql
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input     4096 Mar 22 12:26 performance_schema
-rw------- 1 polkitd input     1675 Mar 22 12:26 private_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 polkitd input      451 Mar 22 12:26 public_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 polkitd input     1107 Mar 22 12:26 server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 polkitd input     1679 Mar 22 12:26 server-key.pem
drwxr-x--- 2 polkitd input     4096 Mar 22 12:26 sys
[root@log001 apollo-mysql]# ls
ApolloConfigDBDEV   ApolloConfigDBUAT  auto.cnf    ca.pem           client-key.pem  ib_logfile0  ibdata1  mysql               private_key.pem  server-cert.pem  sys
ApolloConfigDBTEST  ApolloPortalDB     ca-key.pem  client-cert.pem  ib_buffer_pool  ib_logfile1  ibtmp1   performance_schema  public_key.pem   server-key.pem
[root@log001 apollo-mysql]# lsof ibdata1
[root@log001 apollo-mysql]#
```

where is going wrong about this mysql pod?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of TOP or HTOP from your OS.

Comment: Consider the error message quite literally, is there another mysqld running on the same datadir.